# Unable to get rid of Sality on my Dropbox

Tags: virus, virus-removal

### The story...

As a group of rookie security researchers  who deal with malwares, viruses etc., me and my team-mates sometimes do commit mistakes in handling the binaries. And so, I ended up infecting my own pen drive with one of the malware binaries I was dealing with- **Sality**.

Without realizing that my pen drive is infected, I used it in my own system. 
Fortunately enough, my Anti-virus could catch the infection. And [I thought I was safe](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/25319/9778).
But today morning I saw my AV Avast crying loudly about Sality infections....that too, oddly enough, in my Dropbox's `.dropbox.cache` folder.

For those who do not know about the .dropopx.cache folder, please [have a look here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/328/en).

### What I tried...

I have tried a lot of things to get rid of the infection or to get rid of the files themselves. First, I scanned the infected folder with my AV and got rid of the files. But they came back when Dropbox re-synced.

Next, I did a full system scan with Kaspersky's Sality killer and removed the infected files. But they were again back when Dropbox re-synced, and again my AV started crying.

`shift+DEL`ing the files doesn't help too, since they will still come back when I re-sync. I know this should not be happening as per the link I gave above, but it does happen!.

An important point to note here that our entire group uses Dropbox to share stuff amongst each other. So there *is* a possibility that someone else amongst us also got there system infected, and that is why cleaning my system is not helping me. But the fact that the `cache` folder has the infection makes me feel that infection is from my own system (not very sure here though...)

A snapshot of Avast's logs, for your convenience:

[image]

### The simple question...

What ***on earth*** should I do now?? The whole purose of keeping all my work in Dropbox was to keep it safe from system failures etc. If **that itself** has caught infection, I am doooooomed :(

p.s: I **cannot** possibly *[nuke it from orbit](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/24195/9778)*...else my Supervisor will nuke me!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You're not doomed, everything is gonna be okay.**

1. [Pause Dropbox sync](https://www.dropbox.com/help/180/en) on **all** of the devices associated with this account.
2. Turn off all of the devices that have Dropbox installed and associated with that account, and any other device that you know/suspect they're infected.
3. Now that you know your files are okay on Dropbox, nuke all of the systems you've just turned off.
4. On a machine that you 99.9% trust its integrity, install the Anti-Virus product capable of detecting/cleaning Sality out of executable files.
5. On that machine, install Dropbox and associate it with your account. Watch as your Anti-Virus detect/clean the virus from the files.
6. If there were **no** infections, you're done. If there were infections and the Anti-Virus wasn't able to clean them, wait until all the files are synced and then reboot in safe mode and use [Win32/Sality Remover (from AVG)](http://aa-download.avg.com/filedir/util/avgrem/avg_rem_slt_all_1_616.exe) and  [SalityKiller (from Kaspersky)](http://media.kaspersky.com/utilities/VirusUtilities/EN/salitykiller.exe) to do a final sweeping.

A coupe of notes:

- Infected files on your Dropbox will not magically infect your new clean system unless you run them somehow.
- If you have the option, it's better to restore all your files to a previous version using Dropbox website instead of syncing and cleaning. (it all depends on the age of your infection and whether you have [Dropbox Packrat](https://www.dropbox.com/help/113/en) activated)