# Windows "Send to compressed file" creates an image?

Tags: windows, virus

One of my friends windows laptops (which I don't have access to right now) has in the recent past had a virus (where .doc files were converted to .exe files) which we dealt with.

Now when she right-clicks a folder to "send to compressed file" instead of creating a .zip file it creates an image file (jpg/png variety - will find out which).  Is this known behaviour of a virus?  I can't find anything anywhere about this kind of behaviour.  Avast is not picking it up as a virus, but I can't imagine it being anything but a virus.

Where do I start to fix this?

Comment: image file in sense iso/nrg or jpeg/jpg?

Comment: See http://xkcd.com/1180/

Comment: I would assume, since you say that you dealt with the previous virus, that you ["nuked it from orbit"](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/24195/33). Is this assumption correct, or is your friend's laptop still presumed infected? It is definitely one of the two.

Comment: I didn't nuke it from space, no! Just used avast to remove the virus, but yes that might be a solution!

Comment: Image as in jpg/png - will find out which!

Comment: @AviD Ok, any ideas what it could be?  I can't think why any legit program would do that.

Comment: No, I don't know what would have caused it (nothing *should* have) and I don't know if it IS a virus nor if it IS NOT. My point is it's throwing good hours down a sewage pipe, until you start with a known clean (or at least, not a known-unclean) system. It might just be a simple registry key import, it might not, but I wouldnt bother with it.

Comment: It's like if you take your jalopy to be serviced, you tell him "I just blew a gasket out on the highway, and I know my engine block is cracked. Can you please check the oil?"

Comment: Not really, it's like saying "the car doesn't work anymore" but I can't tell if it is malicious or something I've done to it.  So I think the question seems legitimate.  Nuking from space should not be a first resort.

Comment: No, the issue is that you *know* there was a severe problem (the virus infestation). You did not deal with it properly, and are trying to ignore it. Again, I don't know that it is caused by the virus, but I find it pointless to deal with the little things (like checking oil) before dealing with the big, critical things (like the cracked engine). Here's the thing: If it is a virus / malware issue, in some way, the advice you will get here is as I've said: Nuke It. If it is *not* virus/malware, the question would be off topic here...

Comment: No.  We very probably did deal with it properly.  We simply don't know if it is a virus, hence me asking here if it is a known behaviour of a virus.  Why take the car in for a new engine if it is just the oil?  I would also have thought here was a great place to ask if that behaviour is known virus behaviour.  I think we're done here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type this command in run window

windows xp

```
rundll32 zipfldr.dll,RegisterSendto
```

windows 7

```
regsvr32 %windir%/system32/zipfldr.dll
```

and click ok....

Comment: Which would I do for vista?  Thanks!

Comment: @MattParkins: Downgrade to XP, of course :P

Comment: Ah yes, apply brain.

Comment: please use second one. 7 solution