# Strange name on "shared", was I hacked?

Tags: authentication

I use a Macbook Air 2013 and I recently noticed a very strange and long line of digits and letters under my "shared" category in finder. When I click on the name, it just says "failed to connect." It has a picture of a PC next to the name.

In addition, when my computer goes into sleep mode the screen saver says "test's macbook air" and I never set it to this. Has someone hacked me to "test" their aptitude?

I am not very experienced with this sort of thing and I am slightly worried and taken off guard.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your 1st question, under the shared category in the finder, you will see any hosts on your network with file sharing enabled. This is normal behavior.

Regarding your name showing up as 'test', in system preferences, under User Accounts, check to make sure that the correct Username is showing up. Did you set up this account? Also, under 'Sharing', check to see if any of the File Sharing or Remote Access features are enabled. Unless these are enabled, no other hosts on your network should have been able to access your machine, unless they are exploiting a vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

### As to your first question:

If your macbook is supposed to be the only host on your network, you probably have unwanted company. Note that some devices make themselves visible using a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). What about a recently added mobile phone, TV or appliance on your network?

Assuming you are using a WiFi router: What kind of access control do you use? Consider changing it to WPA2-PSK and choosing a new (good) password / pre shared secret.

### To your second question:

Check 'Users' in the system preferences: Any users you didn't set up? Does executing

```
ps aux
```

come up with any users you do not recognize?

Also, the 'Sharing' system preference: Is the device name set to 'test'?

Did anyone have access to your device and may just have changed it there without hacking, for testing what this does?

You might as well [nuke from orbit](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24195/how-do-you-explain-the-necessity-of-nuke-it-from-orbit-to-management-and-users) after sorting out your network issues to be sure.