# How dangerous are worm:win32/Goldrv!rfn and worm:win32/vbjk?

Tags: malware

Windows defender has detected the following worms on my system and I was wondering how dangerous are they and what is it that they do? [image: Detected Items]

Answer (score 1):

Worm:Win32/Goldrv!rfn is a trojan that installs 
Win32/Rootkit.Agent.HU malware.

*Installation*:
The trojan does not create any copies of itself.

The trojan creates the following files:
*%windir%\­system32\­drivers\­symavc32.sys* 
                      (167936 B, Win32/Rootkit.Agent.HU)
%temp%\­_it.bat

Installs the following system drivers (path, name):
*%windir%\­system32\­drivers\­symavc32.sys, symavc32*

The trojan executes the following files:
*%temp%\­_it.bat*

The trojan deletes the original file.

The trojan may delete the following folders:
*%currentfolder%*

Answer (score 0):

Worms will often give themselves randomized names to avoid user detection, you won't find many worms that will names themselves "IAMAVIRUS.worm".  It's impossible for us to tell what the worms would do without seeing their inner workings, but to be honest you should probably just remove them from your machine if Windows Defender flags them.

Comment: I found some info on the first one from Microsoft's Malware Protection Center but I was looking for a little bit of more details. https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Worm%3AWin32%2FGoldrv!rfn&ThreatID=-2147274438

Comment: I think that the more secure option is to wipe the computer and reinstall.

Comment: In fairness to the guy asking, if Windows Defender flagged the thing, that means Windows Defender recognized it. Or, at least, recognized something about it that was suspicious. If it's a known type of malware, we probably **can** say specifically what it's doing because someone already went to the trouble to analyze it. Of course, the larger question "how did it get on the system?" is murkier.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I want that to be my last option.

Comment: @ParthianShot That's what I want to know, my initial guess would be this flash drive I plugged into my system which had a new folder.exe and a new folder(2).exe in it of which I did not open but one of them disappeared right before my eyes which I found that to be quite alarming.

Comment: Of course you do @KosarF. I understand. See [How do you explain the necessity of nuke it from orbit to management and users?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24195/how-do-you-explain-the-necessity-of-nuke-it-from-orbit-to-management-and-users). schroeder's answer seems the most relevant.

Comment: You didn't mention problems with a flash drive. Destroy it and throw it out. Never plug it into another computer. If you must, use a junker computer to extract the critical information and then reformat  that computer.

Comment: @NeilSmithline Thanks for that "nuke it from orbit" Q&A.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I have already discarded the flash drive.