# phishing from chrome

Tags: phishing

This just showed up in Chrome.

It's obviously phishing - the mangled English and weird url give it away. How would it work? Asking me for info I shouldn't give them?

My system then slowed down. Reboot asked to check files so I did.

Restarted in safe mode with network. Backed up files to another place.

McAfee status OK.

Need I worry about how they managed to hijack my NY Times page to display this?

Need I worry?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you explain the necessity of "nuke it from orbit" to management and users?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24195/how-do-you-explain-the-necessity-of-nuke-it-from-orbit-to-management-and-users)

Comment: `This just showed up in Chrome` is unfortunately not enough information  to give a meaningful assessment of your situation. We would need more details.

Comment: I don't know why there are close votes for the "nuke it from orbit" question. I can't see any reason for this other than it being a snide way to say "you should nuke it from orbit" (which is _really_ silly advice for a phishing attempt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, so it doesn't remain unanswered and may help others.

I thought nuking from space (as suggested) might be overkill. I asked friends and got this advice, which I took:

Googling:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_other-protect_scanning-windows_10/virus-warning-big-red-page-wanting-me-to-call/b451426e-1408-40ff-b171-4c83a149b761

Did you visit Yahoo at some point in that browser session ... ? (No)

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/google-chrome-critical-error/92ddd0e1-b860-4d63-b6af-f8a5da2c159f

Suggests accidentally clicking on an ad as a cause, and suggests
installing an adblocker (and clearing browser history) as a solution.

I also recommend running a complete virus scan before you do anything
else after you clean cache and cookies.

The problem has not recurred.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a full solution, but Chrome has a Malware Scanner built in:
chrome://settings/cleanup

From Google's support page for the Cleanup tool:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2765944?visit_id=637033241183707988-3142379722&p=chrome_cleanup_tool&hl=en&rd=2

> If you're seeing some of these problems with Chrome, you might have unwanted software or malware installed on your computer:
>
> - Pop-up ads and new tabs that won't go away
> - Your Chrome homepage or search engine keeps changing without your permission
> - Unwanted Chrome extensions or toolbars keep coming back
> - Your browsing is hijacked, and redirects to unfamiliar pages or ads
> - **Alerts about a virus or an infected device**

Answer (score -3):

There are two ways to deal with this.

1. Reset the browser settings to default and physically set the home page to `www.google.com`. If that doesn't work, you will need to reinstall Google Chrome.
2. Run a program called [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and delete the hijacking tab.

Comment: There's no way to know if you get everything clean by doing spot fixing like this.